# How to query list of objects with array as an argument in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to query a list of objects having array of IDs. Something similar to following SQL query:

```
SELECT name FROM events WHERE id IN(1,2,3,...);
```

How do I achieve this in GraphQL?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can definitely query with an array of values! Here's what the query itself would look like:

```
{
  events(containsId: [1,2,3]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And the type would look something like:

```
const eventsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'events',
  type: // your type definition for events,
  args: {
    containsId: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)
  },
  ...
});
```

If you wanted to parameterize this query, here's an example of that:

```
{
  query: `
    query events ($containsId: [Int]) {
      events(containsId: $containsId) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    containsId: [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

Comment: what would the schema look like?

Comment: what would the [1,2,3] look like when using query variables instead of hardcoding it directly in the query?

Comment: Adjusted my answer with the above parameterization!

Answer (score 1):

I just do this:

```
query nameOfYourQuery {
  allEvents(filter: { id: { in: [1,2,3] } }) {
    nodes {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

If the array is a variable, then it would look like this (in Gatsby, at least):

```
query nameOfYourQuery($arrayOfID: [String]) {
  allEvents(filter: { id: { in: $arrayOfID: [String] } }) {
    nodes {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't wait for [graphql syntax highlighting to be available on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358925/adding-graphql-syntactical-highlighting-for-code-blocks)...

Comment: allEvents has no argument named \"filter\"". From what I understand the remote side needs to have this option implemented. I don't understand all the hype around graphQL, there is no magic, as api clients, we still need to ask api developper for new features when needed, or do multiples queries in case what we look for is not implemented....

Comment: @Tobbey the hype around graphql is mostly because with it you can query multiple services and have just one endpoint. Also when building frontends separately from the backend "headless" you can use that same endpoint for different frontends. 

With rest apis you have different endpoints for things like products, categories, etc

Answer (score 0):

In my use case I did as:

query:

```
vehicleTypes: { name: ["Small", "Minivan"] }
```

input:

```
vehicleTypes: VehicleTypesInput
```

then use like this:

```
Input VehicleTypesInput {
    name: [String]!
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an input type on a query?