# React-Apollo : Make query calls for a list of variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, github-graphql

Given a list of usernames and the following query to `GITHUB API`:-

```
query.gql:
query USER_QUERY($username:String!){
            user(login: $username){
                  name
                repositories(isFork:false){
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
```

I want to create a `composite query` for every `username`.

Example:

Let's say this is the list of usernames

```
array usernames=["Sheldon","Leonard","Raj","Holowitz"]
```

Expected Query:

```
 {
  sheldon:user(login: "sheldon") {
    name
    repositories(isFork: false) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  leonard:user(login: "leonard") {
    name
    repositories(isFork: false) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  raj:user(login: "raj") {
    name
    repositories(isFork: false) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  holowitz:user(login: "holowitz") {
    name
    repositories(isFork: false) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
```

Is there any `react`ive-way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `react`ive way for this - react is not for glue string templates.

Your expected query is not constructed in the right graphQL way. It might work but you shouldn't think that way - when you need array - just ask for an array. If you really need this kind of structure do it (conversion) after feching 'normal' array - it's a matter of one-liner `.filter()` fn. Don't expect this (strange) format (behavoiur) from universal response.

Read related answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644296/how-to-query-list-of-objects-with-array-as-an-argument-in-graphql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446042/passing-multiple-arguments-to-graphql-query).

Even calling separate queries may be batched by apollo.

Comment: Query is correct wrt graphQL manners. Please refere [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag) for different query format. This is to  enable queries to be separated from script over .graphql||.gql files.

Comment: No, expected query is written in right graph QL way It is aliasing the response for every username

Comment: "It might work but you shouldn't think that way" - I didn't write that it's incorrect - YAGNI - don't complicate simple things

Comment: Okay, seconded. How can I ask for an array if The API simply does not provide that for this api, It just takes single username and responses with the "asked" data for the 
"single username"

Comment: You should wrote that in title/question before. Not your API? Did you read about [batching](https://blog.apollographql.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862)? Simply render list of items, each of them with own query - it should work w/o additional efforts if server support batching - if not ask a new, more detailed question.

Comment: changes made to question

Comment: It doesn't change anything ;) [API is limited in free version] - use separate user component (each with own query) to render their repos (or to save in array). Making  strange workaround isn't worth the effort.

Comment: missing [link](https://platform.github.community/t/how-to-list-up-all-users-in-github/3070/6)